# writing check to pay USPTO is good or not?

Tags: patent-applications

I need to pay USPTO $100 because my Micro Entity Application was filled incorrectly. I plan to pay by check. From the website, I read the following:

*Check or Money Order – make payable to "Director of the USPTO." There is a $50 processing fee for any check returned to the USPTO unpaid*

I am not a regular check user. What does the "any check returned to USPTO unpaid" mean? how could that happen? If USPTO get the money, that extra $50 will not be charged. Am I right?

By the way, I will mail back with my corrected Micro Entity Application. I hope I will only be charged with that $30 surcharge fee.

Comment: I can’t provide an authoritative answer, but I read that to mean there is a $50 fee if the check bounces (in other words there is insufficient funds in your account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the check or money order is good then there should be no problem.